# What is the new function for handleOpenURL in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook

I am Trying to make an app using a old tutorial. so many things have changed since the tutorial was published. I need to make an facebook login, so going through some posts i learned, `FBAppCalls` have changed to `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`, but there was a call like this in the old tutorial

`FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, withSession:PFFacebookUtils.session())`

So what will it be in the new Updates of swift/xcode/fb framworks etc.?

Comment: And this too `func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) { FBSDKApplicationDelegate.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.sessio‌​n()) }`

Comment: Do your problem resolved or need more help

Comment: solved the above problem but now it says
`ld: framework not found FacebookSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: How you added FBCoreKit & FBLoginKit Framework

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method you can use

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
                application,
                openURL: url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation)
}
```

for iOS 9 this method gets called & you should use like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]! as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])

}



func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
```

Comment: `var permissions = ["public_profile"]
        
        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if user == nil
            {
                NSlog("cancelled by user")
            }
            else if user.isNew
            {
                NsLog("user signed up via fb. ")
            }
            else
            {
                NSlog("User logged in via fb.")
            }
        })
    }
`
Pls help with this also; It says,`PFFacebook` has no member with `LoginWithPermissions`

Comment: You can go through this tutorial for whole information http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/